# cmake detect empty directory during build time

Tags: cmake

I have a custom command that is executed if a directory exists. I need to know if the directory is not empty before executing another command.

Question: How to read, detect or get the number of files of a directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can run regular CMake code as script using `cmake -P` as part of build process.
The script itself would contain somethng like

```
file(GLOB RESULT DIR)
list(LENGTH RESULT RES_LEN)
if(RES_LEN EQUAL 0)
# DIR is empty, do something
endif()
```

Comment: I think the correct syntax to get the length of a list is `list(LENGTH RESULT RES_LEN)`, i.e. without the `${}`.